# Dynamically allocate and delete an array of objects in c++

Tags: c++

So I did some research, and so far I have the following (example code):

A class:

```
class my_class {
  my_class(int a, double b);
  ...
}
```

And a dynamic array:

```
my_class **array_t;
```

And initialization (with some random numbers):

```
int amount = 10;
array_t= new my_class*[amount];

for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
   array_t[i] = new my_class(1, 2.0);
}
```

I think this should work, right? At least the compiler is not throwing any errors at me.

Now I would like to **change the size** of array_t.
So I thought the simplest way would be to just delete the array, and allocate new memory for it. I tried this:

```
1: for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
2:   delete array_t[i];
3: }
4: delete[] array_t;
```

And in the next step allocate new memory as shown above.

However I get the following error messages:

```
Line 2: error: expected primary-expression before '[' token
Line 4: error: expected primary-expression before ';' token
```

I read that the for loop is actually not necessary. But anyway none of the two delete statements work..

This might be a really stupid error, but I don't know what is wrong in here :D
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: :Can you post the full code. Also my_class constructor is private by default.

Comment: Did you forget to include your header for `my_class`?

Comment: Also this problem has nothing at all to do with qt. You may be using qtcreator / gcc but there is no qt code here.

Comment: Why not just use `std::vector` and forget this whole exercise?

Comment: It's hard to help with just this amount of code posted.

Comment: Posting full code would probably just be a mess :D Header files are included. I have never used std::vector, however read about it quite a few times already regarding dynamic memory allocation. However, just working with arrays like I tried to do it should work as well, shouldn't it?

Comment: @robo `just working with arrays like I tried to do it should work as well,`  If it were so easy, you wouldn't have an issue.  That's the point -- it isn't easy.   Also, writing one-off allocation and deallocation snippets of code is not the right way to actually learn how to do this.  Instead, create a dynamic array *class*, similar to `std::vector`.

Comment: One part of your issue is that you don't have an array of `my_class` objects but an array of pointers to dynamically allocated `my_class` objects. Just wondering, do you perhaps have a background in Java, C# or similar languages? Other than in those languages, using `new` directly is actually pretty rare in C++, most uses are hidden in e.g. the `std::vector` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

try to write delete [] array_t; in the for cycle. Because in this way you'll "delete" the array. And to reallocate it just use array_t= new my_class[number];

Answer (score 0):

So ok, first of all thank all of you for your help ;)
I just made a stupid programming mistake :D

basically what I typed was:

```
delete my_class[i];
```

instead of

```
delete array_t[i];
```

while iterating through the for loop which gave me the "expected primary-expression before .. token"-error. I got confused with my variables.

The way I posted it above I have tried and it actually works. 
I apologise for the inconvenience ;)

Comment: This is not correct.  For calls to `new[]` you deallocate using `delete []`, not `delete`.